# Apache Camel (version >= 2.16): Using wireTap to route a message to a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm just upgrading from Camel 2.12 to 2.19.1 and run into problems with my `wireTap`expressions:

```
from("direct:start")
    .wireTap("bean:myWireTapBean")
    .to("bean:doSomething");
```

This code is working fine till version 2.15 but from 2.16 on Camel calls  `myWireTapBean` and tries to interpret the `void` result as a dynamic endpoint URI to be called and produced this exception:

```
Stacktrace: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: null to the required type: 
java.lang.String with value null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.resolveEndpoint(SendDynamicProcessor.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As a workaround I can define the route like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .wireTap("bean:myWireTapBean").ignoreInvalidEndpoint()
    .to("bean:doSomething");
```

but the `ignoreInvalidEndpoint()` feels odd to me as `bean:myWireTapBean` is a valid endpoint.

What is the recommended way of using `wireTap` where it does not interpret the provided bean as an expression to calculate a dynamic URI but uses the bean as the endpoint?

Comment: Yeah this is a bit cumbersome, you would need to add a little route as workaround and tap to a direct route where you then call the bean. I have logged a ticket to make it work again with bean directly: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11528 so you can specify if the uri is dynamic or not.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for adding the `dynamicUri(false)` improvement in Camel 2.20.0